# django handling multiple id

Tags: python, django

I have a model

```
class Notification(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here what I want to implement is get the notifications that are not viewed yet and when the user view the notification is should be set to viewed=True.

My notification works perfect with the information and question title. When user clicks the notifications it goes to the detail view of the question.

Here what I want the notification to be set as viewed when user goes to the detail view of the question.

My template file is

```
{% for notification in notifications %}

<p><a href="{% url "question-detail" notification.body.id %}">{{notification.title}}   </a></p>
{{notification.body}}


{% endfor %}
```

View for my question detail view is:

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):

    context = {}

    model = Question
    template_name = "question-detail.html"

    def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):

        self.pk = pk

        return super(QuestionDetailView, self).get(request, pk, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(QuestionDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['question'] = Question.objects.get(pk=self.pk)


        return context
```

and its url is:

```
url(r'^question/(?P<pk>\d+)',QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name="question-detail"),
```

Here I want to set the notification to be viewed=True. How can I get the id of the notification. In the url I am already getting the id of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you are using class based view, you don't need to fetch object by yourself.
Let's simplify your detail view:

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "question-detail.html"
    context_object_name = 'question'
```

This view will produce exactly the same behaviour, as your example.

Next, let's set related to question notification as viewed:

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "question-detail.html"
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        q = context['question']
        Notification.objects.filter(body=q, viewed=False).update(viewed=True)
        return context
```

**UPDATED**

To mark *exact* notification as viewed, provide corresponding notification id in url. Here how it can be done:

urls.py

```
(r'^question/(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<npk>\d+))?',QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name="question-detail"),
```

views.py

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "question-detail.html"
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        q = context['question']
        npk = kwargs.get('npk', None)
        if npk:
            Notification.objects.filter(pk=npk, body=q, viewed=False).update(viewed=True)
        return context
```

template.html

```
{% for notification in notifications %}
    <p><a href="{% url "question-detail" notification.body.id notification.id %}">{{notification.title}}   </a></p>
    {{notification.body}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That didnt worked. Doing this it sets all the notification to viewed=True that is related to the particular question. There might be multiple notifications on single question. Doing this it sets all the notifications to viewed=True while I want the particular notification to be True.

Comment: @Aaeronn yes, this will set **all** notification, related to current question, as viewed. How you identify *particular* notification, i.e. what notification is *particular* and what is not?

Comment: Thanx thats what I was looking for. And one suggestion do passing multiple id in the url look clumsy. I mean is it good way of doing ??

Comment: Nothing bad in doing so in terms of django. Another question, maybe it is a project architecture problem. It is possible, that will be better to create a notification detail view with one id in url and not a question detail view. And in that view you can access to notification itself and to exactly one realted question.

Answer (score 0):

here you can use dajax technique when the user click the notification write a function like onclick = "MakeItAsTrue({{notificaation.id}})" in this function pass the parameter as notifiation id , in side the function call the dajax and take the corresponding user and make that notifiation  viewed=True , then save(), it will work